# Setting expression for two different table attribute to store as default style

Tags: qgis, 3d, expression, geopackage, rule-based

I'm new on QGIS. I would like to store a default style in geopackage use by two different table attribute. First table with "building_height" , and second table with "block_height".

How do I write expression for my rule-based for 3D extrusion. I would like QGIS detect itself when extrusion will use "building_height" when there is "building_height" field and or use "block_height" when there is "block_height".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of one of two attributes, where one of them always is empty (`Null` or `0`), you can use this expression - be aware that [`array_sum`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?#array-sum) is available [since QGIS 3.18](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog318/index.html#feature-support-for-min-max-majority-sum-mean-and-median-functions-on-numerical-arrays):

```
array_sum (array (building_height, block_height))
```

For older QGIS-version, you can use this expression:

```
if (
    (building_height is NULL) or (building_height =0), 
    block_height,
    building_height
)
```

*Demonstration the expression in action: it takes those of the two values that is not `NULL` (empty):*
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!